# Show thread feature as thread symbol in Solidworks drawing

Tags: solidworks

I have a SolidWorks part with a thread feature as shown below.
[image]

Is it possible to show the same as thread symbol in corresponding Solidworks drawing
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm - do you want to show more detail in the drawing, or less detail on the part? (Both are possible!)

Comment: The thread feature looks very congested in the drawing . Instead, I want to show it in a simple way like shown in the figure above.

Comment: You need to remove the fully modelled thread in the part and replace it with a 'cosmetic thread' then - if you want to keep the complex thread e.g. for rendering then you can use configurations for that